# Something like Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols for WebKit?

Tags: c#, webkit, pluggableprotocol

Since years, we are using a WebBrowser component inside our C# .NET application, together with an Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol to handle resources. This used to work perfectly for us. Unfortunately, this approach only works for IE 4 and up as it hooks up in urlmon.dll in Windows.

Now, we are investigating into using a WebKit component for displaying (and reporting) HTML content. Thus, the Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol is not an option any more.

Is there anything similar for WebKit? The idea is to handle URLs like "resource://..." with a custom handler (preferably in C#) to locate the resources and provide them back to the web engine as a stream.

See some examples below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://stylesheets/company_style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Or this:

```
<td class="header">
  <img class="margin" src="resource://images/logo_small.gif" alt="Logo" />
</td>
```